Is there a reaction between rubbing alcohol and hot aluminum when they come together?
I was told by someone very persistent that there is a volatile reaction when rubbing alcohol comes in contact with hot aluminum (think rubbing alcohol squirted on a hot charcoal briquette chimney). Can anyone confirm if this is accurate? Will rubbing alcohol react purely to the aluminum? Or does it need to have fire for the reaction? Thanks!

"volatile" reaction? It could just boil away, like water, but even faster.

Yes, alcohols, including ethanol and isopropanol, both commonly used in rubbing alcohol, do react with aluminum (AKA aluminium), forming aluminum triethoxide ($\ce{Al(OCH2CH3)3}$) and aluminium triisopropoxide ($\ce{Al(CHO(CH3)2)3}$), respectively.
However, that reaction is normally exceedingly slow. At room temperature, an aluminum cap-liner on a bottle of rubbing alcohol may disintegrate over years as it first forms the ethoxide or isopropoxide, which rapidly decomposes in moist air, leaving crumbly aluminum oxide ($\ce{Al2O3}$).
At the temperature of a charcoal brazier, the alcohol will burn off long before it changes the aluminum appreciably. For that matter, at the temperature of burning charcoal, you'd have a puddle of molten aluminum, with a scum of $\ce{Al2O3}$ floating atop.

Chimney tubes don't get terribly hot, some frying pan temp. tops.

@Mithoron, yes, having accidentally melted Al foil onto a stove element, I'll attest to that.

Then you should invest in better stove ;>
